# Can Internal DNS receive records from external Name Servers? (Bind9)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bind, nameserver

I have two external name servers and two internal name servers (ubuntu, BIND9). If I add an address record to the external name servers (ie tape.company.com) my internal name servers will not resolve the address at all. It doesn't seem to be right that I have to add all my external domains to my internal nameservers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be more detailed about what you want.

You can set you internal DNS servers to use other servers as forwarders.

The DNS itself works this way that you mostly have "external" zones which the internal servers resolve by asking other name servers.

If you have a zone for `example.com` on both internal and external servers which differ in their entries, then you've a strange DNS setup. This should be avoided to have the same zone with different content.